# Node JS Rest Service distinct with multimple field

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm developing backend using node js and MongoDB.
I have developed GET and POST request. I have used GET request with a distinct on specific field:

```
router.get('/machine/:brand', function(req,res){
Machine.find({Brand:req.params.brand}).distinct('Version', (err, machines) => {
if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(400).send({ status: 'ko', data: {msg: err.message }});
    console.log(err);
}
res.status(200).send({status: 'ok', data: {msg: 'Brands available', brand:machines}});
});
});
```

this request works well and give me a list of all version for specific brand machine.
Now i need to retrive with version also a model that is other field of machine table.
It's possible to use distinct with 2 field?
How i can retrieve the distinct of 2 field in a unique GET request?

Comment: Can you talk more about your use case?  Are you looking to find all options available or all combinations available?  I mean, let's say someone is searching for cars, brand would be "toyota", are you looking for every year of toyota *and* every body style (sedan, hatchback, etc), or are you looking for every unique combination (e.g all 2010 SUV's)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get easily get the distinct values for two separate fields using one single MongoDB query. It would be possible using the aggregation framework. However, the code would be relatively nasty and you wouldn't be leveraging indexes on your fields, either. So what you can do is this:

```
router.get('/machine/:brand', function(req,res) {
    Machine.find({Brand:req.params.brand}).distinct('Version', (err, machines) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(400).send({ status: 'ko', data: {msg: err.message }});
        }
        Machine.find({Brand:req.params.brand}).distinct('SomeOtherField', (err, someOtherFieldDistinctValues) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return res.status(400).send({ status: 'ko', data: {msg: err.message }});
            }
            res.status(200).send({status: 'ok', data: [
                {msg: 'Brands available', brand: machines},
                {msg: 'SomeOtherField available', someOtherField: someOtherFieldDistinctValues}
            ]});
        });
    });
});
```

This way you have at least one HTTP request only which will call MongoDB twice.